# Creating a nuget package for a native Windows Runtime component

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-runtime, windows-8.1, nuget, c++-cx

I have created a Windows Runtime component using Visual Studio 2013.  I have built it using C++/CX.  I have used the Visual C++ Windows Runtime project template for this, and so the output is a DLL and a winmd file.

I want to create a NuGet package for this component so that it can be used by any kind of a Windows 8.1 Store app project (C++/CX, C# or JavaScript) just by adding a NuGet reference and calling an API.  The consumer of this NuGet package should not be required to worry about anything beyond that.

How do I go about creating such a NuGet package?

Answer (score 4):

I'm working on the same problem myself. It appears that WinRT C++ projects only compile against one specific architecture. As such, using one from a C# portable class library implies you can no longer compile as "AnyCPU" ignorant of the native world! :) So, I haven't found an answer for this from Microsoft per se (in terms of a walkthrough), but I did find an implementation that solved the problem fairly elegantly. Using conditional references, and compiling and shipping all 3 x86, x64, and ARM in one NuGet package, they overcame the issue. With their solution, you can't compile as AnyCPU, but switching between x86, x64, and ARM compiles effortlessly thanks to the conditional reference logic.

The implementation is here on GitHub:
https://github.com/Microsoft/Win2D

Pay special attention to how their nuspec is constructed, how the project builds release artifacts into architecture subfolders, and how they have .targets files for the 3 architectures to apply conditional references to the project you consume their code from.